# How to get started with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have just started with IOS app dev, and was wondering if you'll could help me out a bit with Xcode. I have tried the developer.apple link but the Interface Builder part is not quite clear. I mean at least i am finding it a little challenging to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually read this it's pretty good:

Beginning iPhone 4 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK

The thing is that if you don't know Objective-C, you should get a book on that first, otherwise you'll whack your head trying to understand even the basics examples in the above mentioned book. A good Objective-C book would be :

Beginning Mac Programming: Develop with Objective-C and Cocoa (Pragmatic Programmers)

Comment: No problem, I really don't see why your question was qualified as vague. I'm also interested in what other people think would be the best book about "x".

Comment: Thats alryt, i'm just here for answers, and untill i'm getting it, i'm cool with it. And people have their own perspective of analyzing things, I respect that. :)